# AttributeError: 'MDBoxLayout' object has no attribute 'GerPass'

Tags: python, interface, kivy

I've got a problem when I press the button: I always get the error below. Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem?

main.py:

```
class Tab(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass

class GerPass(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(GerPass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
    def btn1_click(self):
        random_characters = "0123456789AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZzçÇ]}[{?!#$%&*"
        caracteres, pass_origin = 15, ""
        for c in range(0, caracteres):
            pass_add = rd.choice(random_characters)
            pass_origin = pass_add + pass_origin
        self.ids.output1.text = pass_origin
    def btn2_click(self):
        pass_new = ''.join(rd.sample(self.ids.output2.text, len(self.ids.output2.text)))
        self.ids.output2.text = pass_new

class Banzii_Pass(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        self.title= 'Banzii Pass'
        
        Window.size = (800, 300)

        Builder.load_file('banzii_pass.kv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Banzii_Pass().run()
```

banzii_pass.kv:

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    
    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "Banzii Pass"

    MDTabs:
        Tab:
            title: "Gerador de Senha"
            
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: 30

                MDBoxLayout:
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                    spacing: 10

                    MDRectangleFlatButton:
                        text: 'Gerar senha aleatória'
                        on_press: root.GerPass.btn1_click()

                    MDTextField:
                        id: output1
                        hint_text: 'Apenas clique no botão.'
                        multiline: False
                    
                MDBoxLayout:
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                    spacing: 10

                    MDRectangleFlatButton:
                        text: 'Randomizar senha'
                        on_press: root.GerPass.btn2_click()

                    MDTextField:
                        id: output2
                        hint_text: 'Digite sua senha aqui...'
                        multiline: False
```

When i try to run the code, everything seems fine, but when I click on any of the 2 buttons, happend that:

```
line 21, in <module>
    on_press: root.GerPass.btn1_click()

line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__
    AttributeError: 'MDBoxLayout' object has no attribute 'GerPass'
```

I have tried to create a instance of GerPass in .py and pass to .kv, but it have failed too